# how to smoothly generate html page content when auto-logging a user in with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, autologin

The html generated by my php pages depends on whether or not the user is logged in.  For example, if the user is logged in a "logout" link is displayed; if the user is not logged in a "login" link is displayed.

I'm implementing an auto-login function.  When the user logs in they can check a box to keep them logged in.  If they check this box a random id is created and stored into a cookie and stored into the database along with their user info.  (It's similar to the method described [here][1].

The way I'm thinking of implementing this is for the php to generate a javascript function if the user isn't logged in, which will request the cookie from the client.  If the cookie doesn't exist I will show the "login" link on the page or direct the page to the login screen.  If the cookie exists I'll use ajax to pass the cookie to a php script and log the user back in.

What should I do next?  Should I use ajax to generate the "login" or "logout" links?  This makes sense, but I feel like using ajax to generate content that depends on whether or not the user is logged in might get complicated on some of my pages.  Perhaps I could reload the page in javascript?  On this secondary load the php would detect the user as logged in and display the page appropriately.  There might be some flicker though between the two page loads.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this so that it's pleasant for the user would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP to generate the pages anyway, why not do the `if ($is_logged_in) {...}` checks in php?

Just access the cookie as `$_COOKIE['my_autologin_token']`, check if it's valid, and log the user in before starting to output any html code.

Example:

```
<?php

$is_logged_in = check_if_has_session();

if (!$is_logged_in AND isset($_COOKIE['my_autologin_token'])) {
    $token = $_COOKIE['my_autologin_token'];
    // get user id from database, based on $token
    // if is valid token/user_id set $is_logged_in = true;
}

?>
// html content start
<?php if ($is_logged_in) { /* "Log out" link */ } else { /* Login link */ } ?>
```

Comment: I am doing those php checks, but those only help while the session is active. Once the session expires I need to rely on the client's cookie. I'll think about your suggestion of waiting to output html code until after I log the user in. Might work... need to look at my webpages and see how easily I can bolt that on. Thanks.

Comment: Point is – you can access the cookie with PHP, instead of doing it in javascript, and then passing the value to PHP.

Comment: Didn't realize you could access cookies with PHP - this makes life MUCH easier!  Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I looked in the manual and found $_COOKIE, but not $_COOKIES, so you may have a typo.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. I mistyped it once, and then copy-pasted the mistake all over the answer :)